# CkFinder plugin Imageresize plugin quality

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

i'm trying ckFinder and the imageresize plugin; it works but when resizing images the quality of resized images is terrible, and i cannot find a parameter to config image output quality.

I've tried Images.Quality = 100; (.net integration) but no luck.

Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Implement your oun based on some better component...

You can try use simple Thumbnails options without plugin:

```
Thumbnails.MaxWidth = 100;
Thumbnails.MaxHeight = 100;
Thumbnails.Quality = 80;
```

And about Images.Quality, I think it use it only when image is larger than      Images.MaxWidth Images.MaxHeight (default 1600x1200)...

old ckfinder and some plugins are opensource, you can check it and wrote your own;

Comment: CKFinder has never been Open Source. You might be talking about the file manager in FCKeditor instead.